# Can anyone identify this spider? (greater Poland region)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

This is in Poland, in the Greater Poland area, found a few days ago by a garage in the city.

I didn't have any coins on me to give a sense of scale, but the body is roughly 1.5cm long. It was dead when I found it.

I'm curious because I haven't seen any spider like this one during my stay here, they're all tiny specimens normally and this one really stuck out.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a Funnelweb Weaver (family Agelenidae), specifically *Tegenaria atrica*,  based on the patterning of the abdomen and thorax.

> [image: Funnelweb Weaver by Jørgen Lissner]
>
> Female *Tegenaria atrica*, picture by Jørgen Lissner

Their range includes Poland:

> Range: Andorra, Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Czech Republic, Denmark, Faroe Islands (introduced), Finland, France (Corsica), France (Mainland), Germany, Great Britain (Channel Islands), Great Britain (Mainland), Great Britain (Northern Ireland), Greece (Crete), Greece (Dodecanese Islands), Greece (Mainland), Ireland, Italy (Mainland), Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Macedonia, Netherlands, Norway (Mainland), **Poland**, Portugal (Mainland), Romania, Slovakia, Spain (Mainland), Sweden, Switzerland, Ukraine, Yugoslavia (van Helsdingen 2009.1).

Source: http://www.jorgenlissner.dk/families.aspx

Comment: These giant house spiders (atrica/duellica etc) were moved into the Eratigena genus 7 years ago, along with the Hobo spider (E.agrestis). Tegenaria includes the barn funnel weaver and similar.